# Linux Command Line vs Linux Command Pipeline

Tags: linux

Was wondering if someone could tell me what the difference is between these two. Cannot seem an exact answer on the net. Command Line to me means input line and pipeline is the output?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command pipeline is when you connect the output of one command with the input of another:

```
$ cat myfile | sort
```

is one trivial example

A linux command line simply refers to the shell prompt.

Comment: `sort myfile` is enough. A better example would be a combination of `ls` and `grep` for instance

Comment: @StephaneRouberol That's why I said it was a TRIVIAL example!

Comment: @StephaneRouberol So an example, so if I wanted to grab the nonhidden files of the current directory in a reverse order it would be like ... ls -r | grep (something) or no?